# How do I search for a string in a directory of excel spreadsheets and have it return the file name?

Tags: python, excel, search

Below is what I currently have - it's a combination of stuff I've seen in other forums.

All the Excel spreadsheets have the same format and the character string I am looking for is always in Column B.

Ideally I would love if I can search for a string and have it return the file name.

```
import os

keyword = input("Search For?: ")  # ask the user for keyword, use raw_input() on Python 2.x

root_dir = "DIRECTORY"  # path to the root directory to search
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(root_dir, onerror=None):  # walk the root dir
    for filename in files:  # iterate over the files in the current dir
        file_path = os.path.join(root, filename)  # build the file path
        try:
            with open(file_path, "rb") as f:  # open the file for reading
                # read the file line by line
                for line in f:  # use: for i, line in enumerate(f) if you need line numbers
                    try:
                        line = line.decode("utf-8")  # try to decode the contents to utf-8
                    except ValueError:  # decoding failed, skip the line
                        continue
                    if keyword in line:  # if the keyword exists on the current line...
                        print(file_path)  # print the file path
                        break  # no need to iterate over the rest of the file
        except (IOError, OSError):  # ignore read and permission errors
            pass
```

Comment: We would also like to understand what is the problem in this program? is not this working the way you expected? for excel handing, pandas is a good option to try with.

Comment: Python can't read Excel spreadsheets in .xlsx format, except for those in CSV format (which are text files) and not proprietary. To read them in native Excel .xlsx format you will need to download and install some third-party extension module and use it. There are several free ones available.

Comment: Code using functions used like `os.walk`, `os.path.join`, `open`, can be simplified using [`Path` from `pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html). It also eliminates some bugs that can occur in those functions that `Path` handles. It's a great module. -- Here's a table that shows the conversions [https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#correspondence-to-tools-in-the-os-module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#correspondence-to-tools-in-the-os-module]